# Detect if a php file has been included in another php file and serve javascript accordingly?

Tags: php

I am trying to include javascript only when needed using a certain technique:

Pseudo code:

```
if ($this is included in x.php) {
<script>url to script</script>
}
```

I know that there is an is_readable($fileurl) function and  file_exists ($fileurl). Im not entirely sure if I should use those and honestly even less how to make my javascript within the php if statement valid. Any ideas?

Comment: you mean *included* as using `include` or `require`?

Comment: @AedixRhinedale well as in include.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the current file was included in a parent file?

Comment: You can start with http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php , it doesn't completely answer your question but it's something. I was about to mention additional local data, similar to what _Charlotte Dunois_ said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such generic php function. But you could work with constants. You define a constant in the file which includes file x. And in file x you check if the constant is defined.

File which includes:

```
define('ID_FILE', 'file_include');
```

File x:

```
if(defined('ID_FILE')) {
     echo 'I was getting included by a file which defines ID_FILE!';
}
```

Comment: You can also set a dummy flag at included file and check for it. If doesn't exists, means the file wasn't included.

Answer (score 0):

To include file only once use functions [`include_once('path')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [`require_once('path')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). If this file was included previous, calling this once more will omit include:

```
[functions.js]
<script>alert('a');</script>

[index.php]
echo "<html>";
require_once('functions.js');
// Some code...
require_once('functions.js');
echo "</html>";
```

*OUTPUT*

```
<html>
     <script>alert('a');</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if you're asking to detect if the current file is included in a parent or to see if the file was included in the current file. If you are looking to detect if the current file was included in a parent file then Charlotte is on the right track. I would declare a constant in each file something like this:

```
<?php define("FILENAME", "FILENAME"); ?>
```

Then you can use the function `defined()` to see if that constant exists. If it does then you know that file is loaded. Example:

```
<?php if(defined('FILENAME')) { ?>
<script src="file.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

If you are looking to check to see if the file was included in the current file then use the function `get_included_files()` to get a list of the files included.

```
<?php
// This file is abc.php

include 'test1.php';
include_once 'test2.php';
require 'test3.php';
require_once 'test4.php';

$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    if($filename == 'file_youre_looking_for.php') { ?>
        <script src='file.js'></script>
    <?php }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this little ad-hoc solution:

```
function isFileIncluded($filename, $includename){
    return strpos(file_get_contents($filename),$includename) !== false;
}
```

To check if `include.php` is included in `myscript.php`:

```
if(isFileIncluded("myscript.php","include.php")){ /* file is included, do stuff */ }
```

Make sure you use the proper path to you file for the first param, for the second, you can just use the filename.

**It works like this**:

1. Get the source code of the script as a string
2. Searches the source code for the filename of your include
3. If the include filename exists in the source, return true, else false.

*Note: If the filename of the include exists anywhere in the script source it will return true, so if you're making an ajax call to that page or even if you have it in the comments it will return true.*

Comment: I'm not sure what this function tries to do (or for what it's good). It reads a file and looks for the passed string?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, I explained it in an edit. Check my answer again.

Comment: Honestly just because the filename is mentioned doesn't mean said filename gets included. It could also just stand in a comment or in `file_get_contents()`, or whereever else.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, right, I mentioned that in my answer.